# Greasemonkey - How to highlight something ONLY when it has focus?

Tags: javascript, focus, greasemonkey

Ok, I'm writing a script to add hotkeys to the explore page on one of the pet sites I play...  I've managed to set focus to the desired links on key press and even change the background color of the selection when it's selected...

```
var theLinks=theTable.getElementsByTagName('a')

var theCells=theTable.getElementsByTagName('td')

if (theLinks.length==0){
  theTable =document.getElementById('right').getElementsByTagName('table')[1];
  theLinks=theTable.getElementsByTagName('a')
  theCells=theTable.getElementsByTagName('td')
}

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 49) {
    theLinks[0].focus()
    theCells[0].style.color = "#f00"; 
    theCells[0].style.backgroundColor="#fcc";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 50) {
    theLinks[1].focus()
    theCells[1].style.color = "#f00"; 
    theCells[1].style.backgroundColor="#fcc";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 51) {
    theLinks[2].focus()
    theCells[2].style.color = "#f00"; 
    theCells[2].style.backgroundColor="#fcc";
  }
};
```

Now, how do I make the color go back to normal when the link loses focus? 
I tried this:

```
if (event.keyCode === 49) {
  theLinks[0].focus()
    if (theLinks[0].hasFocus()){
      theCells[0].style.color = "#f00"; 
      theCells[0].style.backgroundColor="#fcc";
   }
}
```

But it didn't work, and I have no clue what I'm doing here - so how do I make the highlighting disappear if you click something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *onblur* event. It is automatically fired for the focused element when you focus on another element.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Edit:Or use the *:focus* pseudo-selector

```
a:focus { 
  color: '#f00'; 
  background-color: '#fcc';  
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: But how would I use that to change it back to normal?  Your link doesn't really give me any clues...

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I should have mentioned that. Also, if you just want to change the styling of the element on focus(or blur), use the :focus pseudo-selector. 
a:focus {
   color: '#f00';
   background-color: '#fcc';
  }